# Where did the idea of weeks originate and why do they have seven days?

Tags: ancient-history, time-keeping, mesopotamia

Years, months and days are based on obvious astronomic cycles, which makes them largely standardized and ubiquitous across all societies. Weeks, on the other hand, have no relationship to astronomical observations. Why do we have them and where do the seven days come from, when it just as well could have been more or fewer? A cursory read of the articles on Wikipedia, Britannica and several other sources reveals that weeks appear to originate in Mesopotamia, but none of them explain the number seven in particular. Is its origin unknown?

Comment: You should have a look at [this related question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41350/when-did-the-current-7-day-week-cycle-begin).

Comment: https://www.discovermagazine.com/planet-earth/why-are-there-seven-days-in-a-week gives a good rundown of why.  and the 7 day week is based off of astronomical observations.

Comment: @ed.hank: this is an unbelievably shoddy text. To begin with, they confuse _sidereal_ and _ synodic_ months. Given _that_, I would not rely on it for _anything_.

Comment: @sds: But would anyone then (or anyone but a pedant now) know or care about the difference? Or would they just count the days between full moons?

Comment: @jamesqf: _sidereal_ month is ~27.3 days. _synodic_ month (lunation) is ~29.5 days. In the ancient past everyone knew that "a month is 29.5 days". The text starts with "_The Moon cycle is 27 days and seven hours long, and there are 13 phases of the Moon in each solar year_" This is like saying "Roman caravels were made of Damascus steel". Would you trust such a text?!

Comment: Doesn't Wikipedia's [Week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#History) answer this? If not, can you clarify why not?

Answer (score 4):

Having weeks of seven days is a direct consequence of the lunar cycle. Each 29 day lunar cycle comprises four equal phases of 7.25 days long each. Starting from New Moon:

- Waxing crescent ending in First Quarter;
- Waxing gibbous ending in Full Moon;
- Waning gibbous ending in Third Quarter; and finally
- Waning crescent ending in New Moon.

These seven and a quarter day cycles are readily apparent to all individuals, and comprise an obvious cycle greater than a single day and less than a full month.

In a society without electric street lights, this omnipresent cycle of bright nights under the gibbous moon alternating with much dark nights under the crescent moon is one that drives all evening activities. Groups would time their evening activities to occur under the gibbous moon, and as close as possible to Full Moon.

Note that the day of, and the two days just before and after, the Full Moon are nearly twice as bright as the evenings two days before and after the Full Moon. This [albedo effect](https://www.thevenustransit.com/2012/02/albedo-effect.html) is nearly unique to dust covered surfaces, such as the lunar surface, and is how and why scientists were nearly certain the moon was dust covered long before the Apollo missions in the 1860's.

As for history: The Romans marked [the days of each month](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/roman-calendar.html) relative to the Calends (day following New Moon), Nones (day following First Quarter); and Ides (day following Full Moon) of each lunar cycle.

Having these three brilliantly lit nights each month, under which one might even be tempted to try reading a newspaper, is absolutely unmissable to anyone who is frequently about at night away from streetlights.

For those city dwellers with no experience of this: treat yourself to a true nature experience. Attend a dark night sanctuary twice during the coming year, on a cloudless or nearly so night: once at or within a day of New Moon; and again at or within a day of Full Moon. The difference will astound you.

===

Objections ae raised below that the structure of four seven day weeks in a month is not natural because, at various times and places, other subdivisions lengths of the lunar cycle existed.

That's horse hockey. The seven day cycle is the most common; but that doesn't have to mean it's the only one that makes sense. If a society wished or needed to distinguish the brightest third of the lunar cycle, around Full Moon, it would be natural to do that as well (or instead of) with three nine or ten day cycles. That doesn't invalidate the lunar origin of the seven day week. Being one natural read for such a cycle doesn't
require being the only possible such read.

Comment: A more [nuanced](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/t2png?bg=%23FFFFFF&/seri/PA.../0047/600/0000178.000) approach.

Comment: [citation needed].  If weeks of seven days were a natural outcome of the lunar cycle, then why is there such a profusion of other sub-monthly periods?

Comment: @Lucian: Thank you - but I challenge some of this. I'm just a city boy in one of Canada's largest cities and have no difficulty identifying the evenings of First and Third Quarter when the clouds are absent.

Comment: @Mark: Provide a refence for your claim of "*such a profusion of other sub-monthly periods*". From Sumeria to Rome I know of no such "*profusion*".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, [Rome had an eight-day market cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nundinae).  I don't know what sub-monthly period, if any, Sumer used, but Wikipedia has [a list of sub-monthly cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#%22Weeks%22_in_other_calendars) ranging in length from four days to thirteen days.

Comment: @Mark: [Not all weeks are moon-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nundinae), nor are all moon-based weeks related to moon-quarters; for instance, Egyptians divided the month into three [decans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decan), and the [Dacians](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18259) into five six-day weeks.

Comment: @Mark: Seven day weeks being a natural read of the moon's four quarters doesn't require that it be the ***only possible read***. See my addenda. The existence of other reads just means not all societies were identical and with identical needs from a calendar.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, the problem is that it doesn't really tell you anything: if you round the lunar month down to 28 days, you can get "weeks" of 2, 4, 7, or 14 days; if you round up to 30 days, you can get "weeks" of 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, or 15 days.  Since almost any period of ten days or less can be interpreted as a division of the lunar cycle, the specific lengths of those periods aren't in and of themselves strong evidence that they were derived from the lunar cycle.

Comment: @Mark: You seem to have missed that the Calends, Nones, and Ides were explicitly ***defined*** in terms of the lunar cycle, and specific phases of such., and were the basis of identifying the days of each *month* in Rome, even though it also used non-lunar and non-weekly cycles as well. The question is on the origin of seven day cycles within a month. That other cycles can exist, and even be lunar based, is simply not a valid argument against a lunar origin for seven day cycles.

Answer (score 2):

> <sub>**Where did the idea of weeks originate** and why do they have seven days?</sub>

**The idea of weeks**, not necessarily seven days in length, **originated** independently, across many cultures, and at various times, ultimately for purely utilitarian reasons, such as having a practical, medium-sized time unit, between a day (which is oftentimes too short) and a month (which is oftentimes too long).

> <sub>**Where did the idea of weeks originate** and why do they have **seven days?**</sub>

**The idea of seven-day weeks**, specifically, seems to have **originated** in [ancient Sumer, during the first half of the third millennium BCE](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41350).

> <sub>**Weeks**, on the other hand, **have no relationship to astronomical observations**.</sub>

**Some don't, others do**; thus, the Roman [nundinal cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nundinae) constitutes a clear example of the former, whereas the [Egyptian decan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decan) or the [Dacian six-day week](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18259)<sup>**1**</sup> are regarded as instances of the latter, representing either a third or a fifth of a [lunar month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_month), respectively.

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>Yes, I am well aware that the linked post nowhere explicitly states that the 180 lanky pillars, corresponding to a semester, are periodically subdivided into groups of six, by thirty short, sturdy ones, (also) representing the number of days in a month.</sub>

> <sub>Why do we have them and where do the **seven days** come from, when **it just as well could have been more or fewer?**</sub>

As already stated above, **weeks** containing both a **greater** and a **smaller number of days** did exist throughout history, and across the globe.

> <sub>Why do we have them and where do the **seven days** come from, when it just as well could have been more or fewer?</sub>
>
> <sub>A cursory read of [encyclopedic] articles [...] reveals that **weeks appear to originate in Mesopotamia**, but none of them explain the number seven in particular. Is its origin unknown?</sub>

That is indeed **correct**; specifically, in [Lower Mesopotamia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_Mesopotamia) (particularly, [Sumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumer)), during the [early dynastic period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Dynastic_Period_(Mesopotamia)), as already stated above.

> <sub>Where did the idea of weeks originate and **why do they have seven days?**</sub>
>
> <sub>Why do we have them and **where do the seven days come from**, when it just as well could have been more or fewer?</sub>
>
> <sub>A cursory read of [encyclopedic] articles [...] reveals that weeks appear to originate in Mesopotamia, but none of them **explain the number seven in particular**. Is its origin unknown?</sub>

Though initially stemming from [ancient Sumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Sumer), as already noted *twice* above, the seven-day week only came into widespread use due to the (direct or indirect) influence of the famous [Babylonian empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonia) on the [Greek-Roman world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greco-Roman_world) of [classical antiquity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_antiquity); thus, while not its original inventors, the Babylonians were ultimately responsible for not only *preserving* its continuous usage, but also *facilitating* it unto others; but why would they do that in the first place ?

Of course, part of the reason would be that humans, in general, perpetuate ancestrally inherited customs through the generations, unless they prove either completely unnecessary, or seriously detrimental, or until a significant improvement appears somewhere along the way, thereby altering the long chain of transmission. So, while **tradition** does certainly play an important part, what other reasons could there have possibly been, to help explain not merely its adoption and preservation, but also its proliferation ?

To better understand this, let us take the following factors under more careful consideration:

#### [Babylonian mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_mathematics)

[image]

- Before asking ourselves why or [how Babylonians counted](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61171) days, in particular, let us inquire as to how they counted in general; thus, they are reputed to have employed a rather robust [sexagesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal) counting system:

  - Human beings have **five fingers** on each of their **four members**, hence the use of [decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) and [vigesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigesimal) counting systems, such as that of the [Maya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_numerals), for instance.
  - Apart from this, they also customarily divide things into **halves, thirds**, and **quarters**, hence the occasional use of a [dozenal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duodecimal) base.
  - The smallest numerical value whose mathematical properties satisfy all aforementioned divisibility requirements is **sixty**, which, rather unsurprisingly, and as a direct consequence of the above, possesses a relatively [large number of divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number):

    - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60.
  - Notice that the first or smallest number **absent** from the above list is none other than **seven**.

#### [Babylonian astronomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_astronomy)

[image]

- The **shape** and **position** of the **moon** in the (night) sky repeat periodically, with a mean value of about 29<sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> days for a **synodic month**, and of 27<sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> days for a **sidereal month**, respectively.
- Throughout this time, it passes through four easily discernible **[lunar phases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_phase)**: empty, half-full, full, and half-full again, averaging between 6<sup>5</sup>/<sub>6</sub> days and 7<sup>3</sup>/<sub>8</sub> days, or, in other words, about **seven days**.

But how about other celestial bodies ?

- Indeed, almost all visible lights in the sky move in the same direction, the small number of exceptions known to the ancients being the **seven [classical planets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_planet)**,
- not to mention the [important role played](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades_in_folklore_and_literature) by the **seven stars** of the **[Pleiades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades)** across many ancient mythologies, explaining their presence within various [cuneiform star catalogues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_star_catalogues), such as the [MUL.APIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUL.APIN).

Answer (score -5):

Probably from the Middle East

> [The Iranian calendars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_calendars) or Iranian chronology (Persian : ﮔﺎﻩﺷﻤﺎﺭﯼ ﺍﯾﺮﺍﻧﯽ , Gāh-Šomāri-ye Irāni) are a succession of calendars invented or used for over two millennia in Iran , also known as Persia. One of the longest chronological records in human history, the Iranian calendar has been modified time and again during its history to suit administrative, climatic, and religious purposes. The most influential face in laying the frameworks for the calendar and its precision was the 11 century Persian polymath , hakim Omar Khayyam . The modern Iranian calendar is currently the official calendar in Iran. It begins at the midnight nearest to the instant of the vernal equinox as determined by astronomic calculations for the Iran Standard Time meridian (52.5°E or UTC+03:30 ). It is, therefore, an observation-based calendar, unlike the Gregorian , which is rule-based.

Following the rise of extremist Christianity in Europe, Sunday was declared a holiday instead of a Friday.

Comment: Welcome to HSE. What has your answer to do with the fact that weeks have seven days?

Comment: They **observed** 365 days, the rest is estimates and math. @José Carlos Santos 365÷12≈30 and 30÷4≈7

Comment: It turned out later that a year is 365 days and six hours. So they added a leap year. (A leap year is a calendar year that contains an additional day added to keep the calendar year synchronized with the astronomical year or seasonal year)

Comment: @user52467: Friday is a sacred day for both Jews and Christians; for the former, it represents the [day of preparation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preparation_day) before the [Sabbath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbath); for the latter, it is the day of [Christ's crucifixion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucifixion_of_Jesus). Islam diplomatically chose to adopt this day, so as to express both kinship with, as well as independence from other Abrahamic faiths.

Comment: @user52467 Why 30÷4? Why not 30÷5=6 or 30÷3=10 _exactly_? If this reasoning were true, 6 or 10-day week would be more logical.